How to get colored instructions (prologue/epilogue) from idapro or idapython
I want to identify the prologue and epilogue in the control flow graph. I didn't find any API to get the prologue and epilogue instructions or addresses directly, so I was wondering if I could first color them in the configuration and then extract them by color when running IDAPython scripts.
Is there an API to get them directly? Is the color approach feasible?
I have set the PROLOG_COLOR and EPILOG_COLOR in ida.cfg by adding:
PROLOG_COLOR = 0xE0E0E0 // grey
EPILOG_COLOR = 0xE0FFE0 // light green
SWITCH_COLOR = 0xE0E0FF // pink

However, when I run idc.get_color(address, CIC_ITEM) in IDAPython, the returned color is still the default color. I have also tried ida_nalt.get_item_color(address) which did not work either.
What am I missing here?
